# Laravel 4 - Save url by AJAX

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, http-post, laravel-routing

I have a form to save an 'url'. I want to do it by AJAX, and this is my code:

```
$('#guardar_imagen').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $('#url_imagen_1').serialize();

        $.post('uploadImageUrl/'+url, function(data){
          alert(data); // This alert is to test
        }); 

    jQuery.noConflict()
    $('#nuevaImagen1').modal('hide');

 });
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('uploadImageUrl/{url}', 'ImagenController@uploadImageUrl');
```

But I'm having an error, because the system thinks the `{url}` I'm trying to POST is part of the 'route', and it makes the error.

Any idea how can I send the 'url' to my Controller using AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using post but you're trying to send the data as part of the `route`.

The right way to send data via `POST` is:

```
    $.post('/uploadImageUrl', url, function(data){
       alert(data); // This alert is to test
    });
```

Then your route would be:

```
Route::post('/uploadImageUrl', 'ImagenController@uploadImageUrl');
```

And `ImagenController@uploadImageUrl` would access the data:

```
$imageUrl = Input::get('name-of-parameter');
```

Comment: I've tried it but I can't do anything with my Controlloer... I'm having the next error response: `{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException","message":"","file":"\/Applications\/XAMPP\/xamppfiles\/htdocs\/webs\/lara4\/edu1\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/RouteCollection.php","line":212}}`

Comment: Sounds like you're posting to a route that's not defined. Can you include a `slash` in your `$.post()` .... `$.post('/uploadImageUrl', url, .... `

Comment: If so I have another error: `POST http://localhost/uploadImageUrl 404 Not Found`, and the response is a page telling me that this URL is not located in this server...

Comment: Include a slash in your route too.

Comment: How do you load the default hello view? http://localhost/laravel/public? Then the Ajax request should post to '/laravel/public/uploadImageUrl'. Not sure if you need to revert route to the original. In order to avoid this long prefix you can define a virtual host.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add another word in my route! ;)